# Modifying this simple array creation function on a more Pythonic way

Tags: python, arrays, list, python-2.7

I've the following function, `createFreeSpaces(first_byte, last_byte)` that inputs two numbers `first_byte` and `last_byte` (always integers), and creates a list with the numbers between those two numbers on a specific format. It's very easy, but a bit hard for me to explain, so let's see my try and an example.

Ex:
 `createFreeSpaces(4, 7)`
 
Output:

```
555555 0 0 "FREE: [5.0]"
555555 0 0 "FREE: [5.1]"
555555 0 0 "FREE: [5.2]"
555555 0 0 "FREE: [5.3]"
555555 0 0 "FREE: [5.4]"
555555 0 0 "FREE: [5.5]"
555555 0 0 "FREE: [5.6]"
555555 0 0 "FREE: [5.7]"
555555 0 0 "FREE: [6.0]"
555555 0 0 "FREE: [6.1]"
555555 0 0 "FREE: [6.2]"
555555 0 0 "FREE: [6.3]"
555555 0 0 "FREE: [6.4]"
555555 0 0 "FREE: [6.5]"
555555 0 0 "FREE: [6.6]"
555555 0 0 "FREE: [6.7]"
```

This is my try, as you can see it seems a bit dirty and not so *Pythonic*.

```
def createFreeSpaces(first_byte, last_byte):
    start_bit = 0
    end_bit = 7

    b_start = first_byte + 1
    b_end = last_byte
    b_diff = b_end - b_start

    h = 0
    final_list = []
    while h < b_diff * 8:
        if start_bit == 8:
            start_bit = 0
            b_start = b_start + 1
        final_list.append('555555 0 0 "FREE: [' + str(b_start) + '.' + str(start_bit) + ']"')
        s_start = b_start + 1
        start_bit = start_bit + 1
        h = h + 1
    return final_list
```

I'm cleaning my code so I would like to know if someone can someone give me a hand and tell me how can I make this simple function on a more pythonic way?

Comment: is the input always integer?

Comment: Yes, always integer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you say that the input will always be integer (according to the comments). You can use a single line list comprehension for this. Example -

```
def createFreeSpaces(first_byte, last_byte):
    return ['555555 0 0 "FREE: [{}.{}]"'.format(x,y) for x in range(first_byte + 1, last_byte) for y in range(8)]
```

Making the list comprehension line a bit smaller -

```
def createFreeSpaces(fbyte, lbyte):
    fmt = '555555 0 0 "FREE: [{}.{}]"'
    return [fmt.format(x,y) for x in range(fbyte + 1, lbyte) for y in range(8)]
```

Demo -

```
>>> def createFreeSpacesNew(first_byte, last_byte):
...     return ['555555 0 0 "FREE: [{}.{}]"'.format(x,y) for x in range(first_byte + 1, last_byte) for y in range(8)]
...
>>> pprint.pprint(createFreeSpacesNew(4,7))
['555555 0 0 "FREE: [5.0]"',
 '555555 0 0 "FREE: [5.1]"',
 '555555 0 0 "FREE: [5.2]"',
 '555555 0 0 "FREE: [5.3]"',
 '555555 0 0 "FREE: [5.4]"',
 '555555 0 0 "FREE: [5.5]"',
 '555555 0 0 "FREE: [5.6]"',
 '555555 0 0 "FREE: [5.7]"',
 '555555 0 0 "FREE: [6.0]"',
 '555555 0 0 "FREE: [6.1]"',
 '555555 0 0 "FREE: [6.2]"',
 '555555 0 0 "FREE: [6.3]"',
 '555555 0 0 "FREE: [6.4]"',
 '555555 0 0 "FREE: [6.5]"',
 '555555 0 0 "FREE: [6.6]"',
 '555555 0 0 "FREE: [6.7]"']
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks a lot, Anand.